# FileNotFoundException although file exists in Android 13

Tags: android, android-permissions, filenotfoundexception

hopefully someone can guide me into the right direction.

I want to open and read at least my own gpx file.
Therefore, I use this code, however, I am always getting the error: FileNotFoundException although I was able to select my created gpx file!

Here is my code

```
public void importGPX(View view) {
    Intent data = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    data.setType("*/*");
    data = Intent.createChooser(data, "Choose a file");
    startActivityResultLauncher.launch(data);
}
ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> startActivityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
        new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
        new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
                // Handle the returned Uri
                Log.d("onActivityResult", "FileChooser works");
                File f = new File(result.toString());
                FileInputStream inputStream = null;
                try {
                    inputStream = new FileInputStream(f);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                int i;
                try {
                    i = inputStream.read();
                    while (i != -1) {
                        byteArrayOutputStream.write(i);
                        i = inputStream.read();
                    }
                    inputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                String s = byteArrayOutputStream.toString();
                Log.d("FileContent", s);
            }
        });
```

I also added the following permission, just in case I need them.

```
<!-- Required only if your app needs to access images or photos
 that other apps created. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />

<!-- Required only if your app needs to access videos
     that other apps created. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO" />

<!-- Required only if your app needs to access audio files
     that other apps created. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO" />

<!-- If your app doesn't need to access media files that other apps created,
     set the "maxSdkVersion" attribute to "28" instead. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="32" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="29" />
```

Later, I would like to open other gpx files which were not created by me.
But first I would be glad if I can open my own gpx file.

Thank you very much for your help in advance.

Comment: `// Handle the returned Uri` Indeed that is what you should do. Instead you are messing around with it and using the File class which is not posfible.

Comment: Use the uri in getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri,) and then read from the stream as if it was your FileInputStream.

Comment: `would like to open other gpx files which were not created by me.` You can let the user choose any gpx file with ACTION_GET_CONTENT. Has nothing to do with file owner.

Comment: `also added the following permission, just in case I need them.` In vain. You do not need any permission to use ACTION_GET_CONTENT.

Comment: `i = inputStream.read();` That will read only one byte. Find the better way.

Comment: You are right, I messed it up and the Uri was the missing part. Thank you very much!